# tkinter callback function hangs GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a very simple tkinter program. On the button press ("Insert random number") I want to display a random number. This works well but somehow the GUI becomes unresponsive / is stuck after pressing the button. How can I fix this?

Here's my current code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random

def function_a():
    list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    Output.configure(text=random.choice(list_a))
    Output.after(1000, lambda: Output.configure(text='It is ' + str(random.choice(list_a))))

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('WindowA')
window.minsize(400, 400)

Button = tk.Button(
    master=window,
    text='Insert random number',
    command=function_a
)
Button.pack()
Output = tk.Label(master=window)
Output.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: when I change your code to this `def function_a():
    list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    random_number = random.choice(list_a)
    Output.configure(text=random_number)
    
    def closure():
        display_text_with_prefix(random_number)
    
    Output.after(1000, closure)` where `def display_text_with_prefix(number):
    Output.configure(text='It is ' + str(number))` the GUI does not block / hang. Is that addressing your problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem. When I change your code, adding a separate callback function `closure()` which in turn calls `display_text_with_prefix` the GUI does not block / hang for subsequent button presses anymore.

```
def function_a():
    list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    random_number = random.choice(list_a)
    Output.configure(text=random_number)

    def closure():
        display_text_with_prefix(random_number)
    
    Output.after(1000, closure)

def display_text_with_prefix(number):
    Output.configure(text='It is ' + str(number))
```

I'm not sure it this is an issue with the specific tkinter version or not. If I choose to not use the `display_text_with_prefix(random_number)` call and execute `Output.configure` directly inside of `closure()`, the GUI hangs again.